# scaleTimeRange for Video Preventing Export of Video in Swift 2.0+ on Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

I am using AVFoundation to record a video in a custom camera application. The following code below successfully captures video from a previewView and turns it into a video asset that is saved to the device's Photo Library. I want to have the app use an effect to turn the video in to a slow motion video and have heard people say that `AVMutableComposition`'s `scaleTimeRange` can do the trick. But when I try to implement **as shown in the code below** the video is not exported and the effect is not in slow motion.

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {

    if(error != nil){
        print(error)
    }

    self.lockInterfaceRotation = false

    let backgroundRecordId: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = self.backgroundRecordId
    self.backgroundRecordId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

    //create mutable composition of video and slow it down

    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: outputFileURL, options: nil)
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let sourceVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] 
    let sourceAudioTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]
    do{
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), ofTrack: sourceVideoTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

        try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), ofTrack: sourceAudioTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    }catch _ {
        print("ERROR could not insert time range")
        return
    }

    /* ** THE PART THAT ISN'T WORKING - When I add this section everything breaks **
    //slow video down for slow mo effect
    let videoDuration = videoAsset.duration;
    let videoScaleFactor = 2 * videoDuration.value

    videoTrack.scaleTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDuration), toDuration: CMTimeMake(videoScaleFactor, videoDuration.timescale))
    */

    // Make mutable combination
    // -- Create instruction
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
    let videoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [videoLayerInstruction]

    let mutableComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mutableComposition.renderSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
    mutableComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 20)
    mutableComposition.instructions = [instruction]

    // -- Get path
    let fileName = "/editedVideo-\(arc4random() % 10000).mp4"
    let allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let docsPath = allPaths[0] as NSString
    let exportPath = docsPath.stringByAppendingFormat(fileName)
    let exportUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(exportPath as String)

    print("Tracks before export: \(mixComposition.tracks.count). File URL: \(exportUrl)")

    // -- Remove old video if exists
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(exportPath as String) {
        print("Deleting existing file\n")
        do{
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(exportPath as String)
        }catch _ {
            print("Error deleting old video file")
        }

    }

    // -- Create exporter
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter!.videoComposition = mutableComposition
    exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    exporter!.outputURL = exportUrl
    exporter!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    // -- Export video
    exporter!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        self.exportDidFinish(exporter!)
    })

}

func exportDidFinish(exporter: AVAssetExportSession) {

    // Save video to photo album
    let assetLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
    assetLibrary.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(exporter.outputURL, completionBlock: {(url: NSURL!, error: NSError!) in
        print("Saved video to album \(exporter.outputURL)")
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error saving video")
        }
    })

    // Check asset tracks
    print("SUCCESS exporting video")
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work in the end by taking out the audio and doing the following:

```
let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.pathToMovie), options: nil)
let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

do {
  try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), ofTrack: (videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).first)!, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
} catch {
  print("handle insert error")
  return
}

let videoDuration = videoAsset.duration

//slow down the video to half speed (change multiplier to desired value)
let finalTimeScale : Int64 = videoDuration.value * 2

compositionVideoTrack.scaleTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDuration), toDuration: CMTimeMake(finalTimeScale, videoDuration.timescale))

let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let finalURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("what_you_want_to_call_your_video.mp4")

//make sure no other file where this one will be saved
let manager = NSFileManager()
do {
  try manager.removeItemAtPath(finalURL.path!)
} catch {
  print("file doesn't exist or couldn't remove file at path")
}

let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
exporter!.outputURL = finalURL
exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4 //AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie, whatever format you want that AVFoundation does
exporter!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
                switch exporter!.status{
                case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
                    print("failed \(exporter!.error)")

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        print("Error saving video is \(exporter!.error!.description)")

                        //Show an alert
                        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error Exporting Video", message: "\(exporter!.error) \(exporter!.error!.description). Please try again", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                        //Create and add the Cancel action
                        let okayAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
                            //Do some stuff
                        }
                        alertController.addAction(okayAction)

                        //Present the AlertController
                        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
                    print("cancelled \(exporter!.error)")

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        print("Error saving video is \(exporter!.error!.description)")

                        //Show an alert
                        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error Exporting Video", message: "\(exporter!.error) \(exporter!.error!.description). Please try again", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                        //Create and add the Cancel action
                        let okayAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
                            //Do some stuff
                        }
                        alertController.addAction(okayAction)

                        //Present the AlertController
                        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
                default:
                    print("complete, now presenting confirmation")

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        //everything is done, do what you want to do now that video is created
                    })
                }

            })
```

Comment: do you know of any way when exporting the video and audio in slow motion to have the pitch go down as well. The audio slows down but does not change the pitch...